# How can I insert a row below if the cell contains a value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a row below if in one column contains 12345

My code is not working because is not inserting anything

```
Sub Macro 1()
    Dim i as Integer, inttofind as Integer, app as range, cell as   range
    inttofind=12345
    For i=10 to 6000
        If cells(I,137).Value = inttofind Then
            Cell.offset(1).insert
        End if
    Next I
End sub
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and explain what you mean by "not working".

Comment: You've got some syntax issues, should be `Set app= Range("EG:EG")` though don't need the whole column (in fact you don't use this variable). And `Cell.offset(1).entirerow.insert` if you want to insert a whole row, and you should loop backwards when doing this.

Comment: You code don't compile, `Macro 1` is an invalid name (no blanks allowed) and `Interger` is an invalid data type.

Comment: Yes please post code as is, don't type out from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues with your function.

As well as what has already been pointed out, I would suggest fully qualifying your range with the workbook and worksheet. That way, if the macro runs while you are in a different book/sheet, it won't cause issues.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim RngToCheck As Range
    Set RngToCheck = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("EG10:EG6000")
    Dim ValToFind As Long
    ValToFind = 12345

    Dim i As Long
    For i = RngToCheck.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If RngToCheck(i).Value = ValToFind Then
            RngToCheck(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```